# Получение ссылки на экземпляр суперкласса

Tags: java, наследование

Пытаюсь разбираться с наследованием в `Java`. Есть некоторый код:

```
class A {
    A getThis() {
    System.out.println("call getThis() from A");
    return this; //(3)
    } //(3)

    Object getSuper() {
    System.out.println("call getSuper() from A"); 
    return null;}
}

class B extends A {
    B getThis() {
    System.out.println("call getThis() from B"); 
    return this;
    }

    A getSuper() {
    System.out.println("call getSuper() from B"); 
    return super.getThis();
   }
}

class Tester {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Object a = new B().getSuper(); //(1)
        System.out.println(a);
        a = new B().getSuper().getSuper(); //(2)
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

В результате на консоль выводится следующий текст:

> call getSuper() from B
>
> call getThis() from A
>
> B@25154f
>
> call getSuper() from B
>
> call getThis() from A
>
> call getSuper() from B
>
> call getThis() from A
>
> B@10dea4e

Я ожидал, что при отработке строки (1) в `a` будет лежать экземпляр класса `A`, а после отработки строки (2) в `a` будет лежать `null`. Почему в результате возврата `this` из строки (3) возвращается ссылка не на родительский класс, а на исходный?

---

Как я понимаю, при создании экземпляра класса `B`, в нём хранится ссылка на экземпляр родительского класса `A`. Я вижу косвенное подтверждение своих слов:

При вызове конструктора класса `B` происходит вызов конструктора класса `A`.
Даже при переопределении метода `f` в классе B можно добраться до метода `f` класса `A` через конструкцию `super.f()`;
Несмотря на это, при работе с экземпляром класса `B`, я не вижу способа вернуть из него ссылку на экземпляр класса `A`, который используется в нём. Есть ли какой-то способ всё же реализовать такую возможность?

Comment: `A a = new B()`?

Comment: С точки зрения ООП, B - это и есть A, потому вы и можете использовать B там, где ожидается A. Кроме того, при необходимости можно скастовать ссылку.

Comment: @free_ze я понимаю это, но меня интересует именно ответ на поставленный вопрос). `A a = new B();` тоже не является ответом на вопрос, так как мы лишь производим восходящее преобразование. По ссылке `a` всё равно будет храниться экземпляр класса `B`. Даже при вызове `a.f();` сработает вызов переопределенного метода, но не базового.

Comment: *"Как я понимаю, при создании экземпляра класса B, в нём хранится ссылка на экземпляр родительского класса A. Я вижу косвенное подтверждение своих слов:"* - нет, вы понимаете неправильно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov специально создал новую тему. Можете, пожалуйста, подробнее пояснить, почему я не верно мыслю?

Comment: @Roxio0 потому что никакого "экземпляра класса A" в вашем случае не существует. А значит, и ссылки на него быть не может.

Comment: @PavelMayorov можете ли вы, пожалуйста,  приложить ссылку, где можно было бы подробнее прочитать о реализации классов и наследования в jvm? Т. к. я всё ещё не могу принять вашу точку зрения.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Мне кажется вы путаете понятия Класс и объект.

**Класс** – это способ описания сущности, определяющий состояние и поведение, зависящее от этого состояния, а также правила для взаимодействия с данной сущностью (контракт).

**Объект (экземпляр)** – это отдельный представитель класса, имеющий конкретное состояние и поведение, полностью определяемое классом.

Ключевое слово this указывает не на класс, а на экземпляр класса (объект). Ключевое слово super  обеспечивает доступ к свойствам и методам  этого же объекта но описанным в суперклассе.

Например: Вы создали объект `бирюса` класса `Холодильник`, а класс `Холодильник` наследуется от класса `БытоваяТехника`. Объект `бирюса` является и холодильником, и бытовой техникой. this вернет ссылку на объект `бирюса`, не важно через какой класс получена ссылка `Холодильник` или `БытоваяТехника`, объект от этого не меняется.

Так и у вас объект `a` является экземпляром класса `B`, одновременно является экземпляром класса `А`, так как от него наследуется. Когда Вы вызываете метод getSuper() по цепочке в итоге возвращается this, то есть ссылка на объект `a`

Определения класса и объекта взяты [отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/87119/).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Но моё любопытство не удовлетворено) Как я понимаю, в super удерживается ссылка на экземпляр суперкласса. Могу ли я каким-то образом всё же явно вернуть её из экземпляра расширенного класса?

Comment: Объект один - `a`. Вы можете сделать так:

    `B b = new B();
    A a = b;`

Переменные `а` и `b` будут указывать на один и тот же объект.

Comment: Мы лишь делаем восходящее преобразование в таком случае, объект же остаётся тем же самым. Это не совсем то, что я хотел)

Comment: *"Как я понимаю, в super удерживается ссылка на экземпляр суперкласса"* - нет, вы понимаете совершенно неправильно. super - это не переменная и не ссылка, super - это ключевое слово, которое позволяет вызвать метод суперкласса и не более того.

Answer (score 6):

*Данный ответ был дан на вопрос «[Ссылка на суперкласс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560963/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81)», влитым сюда. Он имел несколько иную формулировку.*

---

1. > Как я понимаю, при создании экземпляра класса `B`, в нём хранится ссылка на экземпляр родительского класса `A`.

   Нет, не хранится. Экземпляр класса `B` — это *и есть* экземпляр класса `A`. Чтобы стало понятнее, рассмотрим, как реализован механизм наследования в Java, C++ и ряде других языков.

   Пусть класс `A` задан следующим образом:

   ```
   public class A
   {
       public int Foo;
       private short Bar;
   }
   ```

   Тогда экземпляры данного класса будут иметь в памяти следующий вид:

   ```
   ref -> +-----------------------+
          | Внутренние данные JVM |
          +=======================+
          | Foo                   |
          +-----------------------+
          | Bar                   |
          +-----------------------+
   ```

   где `ref` — ссылка на область памяти с данными экземпляра класса.

   На вышеприведённой схеме можно заметить две особенности:

   1. Открытые и закрытые поля класса хранятся вперемешку; модификаторы доступа действуют лишь на этапе компиляции при проверке правомерности обращений к полю.
   2. Виртуальная машина Java хранит рядом с данными собственно класса ещё и свои, внутренние данные. В зависимости от конкретной виртуальной машины это могут быть: счётчик «умного» указателя, ссылка на метаинформацию или же ссылка на таблицу указателей на переопределённые методы функций.

   В случае наследования:

   ```
   public class B extends A
   {
       public AnotherClass Foo2;
       private int Bar2;
   }
   ```

   к данным, присущим родительскому классу, в конец приписываются данные, присущие классу дочернему:

   ```
   ref -> +-----------------------+
          | Внутренние данные JVM |
          +=======================+
          | Foo                   |
          +-----------------------+
          | Bar                   |
          +=======================+
          | Foo2                  |
          +-----------------------+
          | Bar2                  |
          +-----------------------+
   ```

   Вся эта связка и обозначает экземпляр класса `B`. Можно заметить, что ссылка на него в точности совпадает со ссылкой на экземпляр класса `A`. Как результат, приведение ссылок вверх по иерархии — это просто *переобозначение* уже имеющейся ссылки.

   А «ссылка на экземпляр родительского класса» используется в классах *вложенных*, которые действительно ссылаются, вот только не на родительский, а на *замыкающий* класс.
2. > Несмотря на это, при работе с экземпляром класса B, я не вижу способа вернуть из него ссылку на экземпляр класса A, который используется в нём.

   Восходящее преобразование типов всегда выполняется неявно (автоматически):

   ```
   B foo = getFoo();
   A bar = foo;
   ```
3. > 1. При вызове конструктора класса `B` происходит вызов конструктора класса `A`.
   > 2. Даже при переопределении метода f в классе B можно добраться до метода f класса `A` через конструкцию `super.f()`;

   Вся эта магия происходит за счёт того, что виртуальной машине известна вся иерархия всех классов, за счёт чего она может явно или неявно подставлять обращение к методам вверх по иерархии.

Answer (score 4):

Для того, чтобы понять почему нельзя получить ссылку на экземпляр базового класса при вызове метода этого класса, в наследнике нужно понять, как работает вызов унаследованного метода в java.

Первое, у нас создается один объект в памяти со всеми полями,    унаследованными от родителей. И этот объект доступен по одной ссылке и никаких вложенных родителей он не содержит. Сравните ссылки `this` при    вызове конструктора `A` и `B`.

```
public A(){
    System.out.println(this);
}
public B(){
    System.out.println(this);
}
```

Второе, методы экземпляра хранятся отдельно от полей объекта и унаследованные методы от класса `A` вызываются даже для объекта `B` через класс `А`. Но при вызове унаследованных методов, в них передается ссылка на экземпляр потомка, их вызывающего. Таким образом, метод как бы вызывается на фактическом экземпляре созданного объекта.

> [Note that methods called using the invokespecial instruction always
>   pass this to the invoked method as its first argument.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.7)

Answer (score -1):

Вызов конструктора класса А при создании класса-наследника В выполняется на уровне работы JVM и только для того, чтобы инициализировать поля объекта класса В, программно эту ссылку получить нельзя, т.к. объекта класса A не существует. А вот если бы класс В был inner классом класса А, то в нём бы хранилась ссылка на объект класса А.