# Ссылка на суперкласс

Tags: java, наследование

Сразу оговорюсь, вопрос не имеет практическую ценность. Интересует лишь сама возможность реализации. Есть базовый класс и унаследованный от него:

```
class A {
    void f() {System.out.println("A");}
}

class B extends A {
    void f() {System.out.println("B");}
}
```

Как я понимаю, при создании экземпляра класса B, в нём хранится ссылка на экземпляр родительского класса A. Я вижу косвенное подтверждение своих слов:

1. При вызове конструктора класса B происходит вызов конструктора класса A.
2. Даже при переопределении метода f в классе B можно добраться до метода f класса A через конструкцию super.f();

Несмотря на это, при работе с экземпляром класса B, я не вижу способа вернуть из него ссылку на экземпляр класса A, который используется в нём. Есть ли какой-то способ всё же реализовать такую возможность?