# Что собой представляют this и super

Tags: java

Помогите, пожалуйста, с теорией. Можно и практические примеры.

Разбирал `this` и `super`. Что я понял: `this` - это ссылка на самого себя. То есть я не могу из другого класса обращаться через `this`. Если пропишу в другом классе, то получу еще одну ссылку на класс, но не другой, а снова себя.

А `super` - это получение методов предка, но только последнего, а не предка его предка. Так ли это? Или я где-то недопонял?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`super` - это указание компилятору обратиться невиртуальным образом к родительскому методу на текущем объекте (`this`). Именно поэтому его нельзя сохранить в переменную.

Answer (score 20):

this - это ты. super - это твоя мамка. Если ты говоришь this и super ты имеешь в виду себя и свою мамку. Если я говорю this и super - я указываю на себя и на свою мамку, а никак не на тебя и не на твою мамку (это если моя и твоя мамка не один и тот-же человек).

Comment: o_O нечего добавить

Comment: нормальный пример привел)

Comment: Лучшее определение для понятия. Но на собеседованиях так говорить, конечно, не надо)))

Comment: @pavel163 ну а что, сказал собеседующему super - это твоя мамка и сразу на работу возьмут.

Comment: @katso можно еще добавить "ты - это твоя мамка" (это ж Java и ООП, наследник *является* родителем). Ужасная и дико дырявая абстракция.

Comment: @PashaPash, на "ты" и "мамка" надо смотреть не с точки зрения инстанса класса (он - один), а с точки зрения таблицы виртуальных функций - они разные.

Comment: @Qwertiy тем хуже -  получается что то, что "он и мать" не один большой человек, а два разных - это всего лишь деталь реализации :)

Comment: @PashaPash, у каждого класса своя таблица виртуальных функций. Это две разные таблицы, не одна и та же. Но таблица потомка в некотором смысле является дочерней для таблицы родителя - она содержит те же функции кроме переопределённых и новых. Кстати, прототипное наследование что-то вспомнилось :) Так что в такой интерпретации ответ корректен.

Comment: @Qwertiy в терминах классов - да. в терминах инстансов - нет. и потом кто-то приходит и спрашивает что-то вроде "а как на эту мамку получить ссылку" http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560889/.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну если очень постараться, то, наверное, можно и получить? Только пошаманить с рантайм-патчингом кода немного)))

Answer (score 8):

В соседнем ответе от @Xoxole представителями сообщества были обнаружены недостатки. А в частности, мать и ребёнок это разные объекты, а `this` и `super` -- один.
Попытаюсь их исправить.

`this` - это ты сейчас, т.е экземпляр человека взрослого, умеющего читать и писать. `super` -- это всё что тебе осталось от себя в младенчестве, умеющего кушать с бутылочки. Если ты говоришь `this` и `super` ты имеешь в виду себя и себя в детстве. Если я говорю `this` и `super` -- я указываю на себя и себя в младенчестве, а никак не на тебя сейчас или в детстве. Когда ты и я стали взрослыми людьми, мы переопределили способность кушать с бутылочки на способность кушать с тарелки вилкой. Но мы всё еще можем кушать с бутылочки (вызывать методы `super` сами по своему усмотрению), но уже никому этого не покажем -- если нам предложат пообедать другие , то мы согласимся только при наличии тарелки и вилки.