# Почему ссылка С++ не может быть переопределена?

Tags: c++, ссылки

Вики содержит информацию о том, что ссылка не может быть переопределена.
Но нижеследующий код исправно работает, причем компиляция проходит успешно с  множеством ключей (Wall, Werror, pedantic, ...)
(gcc version 5.4.0 20160609)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 112358;
    int &ref = a;

    std::cout << ref << std::endl;

    int b = 2718;
    ref = b;
    std::cout << ref << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
112358
2718
```

Comment: определение и присваивание совершенно разные  понятия и действия

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дополните ваш код еще одной строчкой:

```
cout << a << endl;
```

и вы поймете, что ссылка не может быть переопределена - она всегда связана с одним и тем же адресом в памяти...

В своем коде вы выполнили, по сути, присваивание

```
a = b;
```

Comment: нагляднее будет, если перед выводом присвоить  0 обьекту а

Answer (score 3):

В свое время, для собеседований я запомнил одну отличную фразу: 
**"Ссылка это второе имя объекта."**
В своем примере вы записали b в a, по второму имени a. Из выше написанной фразы даже логично что если во дворе есть Коля, по кличке Череп, будет странно если черепом вдруг станет другой человек, даже если с Колей что-то случиться =/, черепом все равно будет только Коля.

Comment: [Напомнило](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593701/176217)

Answer (score 1):

Относитесь к ссылке как к константному указателю