# вызов метода объекта , сразу после Object.create(__proto__), проблема с return this!

Tags: javascript, this

есть рабочий код:

```js
var Person = {
    constructor: function(name,age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
  }
};

var One = Object.create(Person);

One.constructor("Alex", 32)

console.log(One.name);
console.log(One.age);
```

вроде бы всё понятно, создаётся объект `Person`, который в последующем станет прототипом для `One`, для этого вызываем `Object.create(Person)`, потом используем его метод`One.constructor("Alex", 32)`, и вуаля, всё прекрасно работает! Но увидил другую реализацию данного кода, и завис:

```js
var Person = {
    constructor: function(name,age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    return this
  }
};

var One = Object.create(Person).constructor("Alex", 32);


console.log(One.name);
console.log(One.age);
```

С одной стороны я понял, что `Object.create(Person)` возвращает ссылку на объект `Person`, ну и можно сразу вызвать его метод `constructor` с нужными нам аргументами, для создания объекта One . . . Но, код работает лишь в том случае, когда в теле функции `constructor: function(name,age){...}` прописано `return this`! Объясните мне пожалуйста, в чём суть? Какой объект мы возвращаем, и почему без него не работает? Спасибо!

Comment: чет вспомнилось) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593694/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82-this-%D0%B8-super/593701#593701

Comment: Суть в том, что во втором случае вы пихаете в переменную One то, что возвращает функция constructor. А в первом случае вы не пихаете, поэтому там return this не обязателен

Comment: Ничего всё равно не понял

Comment: @andreymal, лучшее объяснение, из тех, что может быть на stackoverflow (нет)